# FLEX AIR project directory structure for storing LOW and HIGH resolution images

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

Any idea what directory structure should one follow for Flex AIR projects in which there is need to store both low and high resolution images so that the low-res images will be used when the app is loaded in a MOBILE and hi-res image will be used when loading the app in a TABLET.

Comment: Directory structure doesn't matter.  Is this really a programming question?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I was actually trying to find a way to load icons/images of appropriate resolution corresponding to the device screen size. Seems like the MultiDPIBitmapSource helps achieving this.

Comment: Understood; it was not obvious that was your goal based on your question.  Technically DPI is independent of screen size.

Comment: Yeah I agree, DPI is independent of screen size, but low resolution images may not look good in a bigger screen - isn't it? So there is a need here for the application to decide between low/high resolution images for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="BACK"
        source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/low-res/back.png')"
        source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/mid-res/back.png')"
        source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/high-res/back.png')"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="portrait"/>
    <s:State name="landscape"/>
</s:states> 

<s:navigationContent>
    <s:Button icon="{BACK}" label.landscape="Back" click="navigator.popView()"/>
</s:navigationContent>
```

See the doc [Support multiple screen sizes and DPI values in a mobile application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html)